# DecisionTreeRegressor under the hood of GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, regression, ensemble-modeling, natural-gradient-boosting

I'm inspecting the weak estimators of my GradientBoostingClassifier model. This model was fit on a binary class dataset.

I noticed that all the weak estimators under this ensemble classifier are decision tree regressor objects. This seems strange to me intuitively.

I took the first decision tree in the ensemble and used it to predict independently on my entire dataset. The unique answers from the dataset were the following:

```
array([-2.74, -1.94, -1.69, ...])
```

My question is: why and how does the gradient boosting classifier turn the weak estimators into regressor tasks (instead of classification tasks) that are not bound by 0 and 1? Ultimately the GradientBoostingClassifier outputs a pseudo-probability between 0 and 1: why aren't the ensemble of weak estimators doing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through more of the documentation I found the section that covers the classification case. It can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#gradient-boosting). Additionally this [statquest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxuNLH5dXCs&ab_channel=StatQuestwithJoshStarmer) was very useful.

> 1.11.4.5.2. Classification
>
> Gradient boosting for classification is very similar to the regression case. However, the sum of the trees
> is not homogeneous to a prediction: it cannot be a class, since the trees predict continuous values.
>
> The mapping from the value
> to a class or a probability is loss-dependent. For the deviance (or log-loss), the probability that
> belongs to the positive class is modeled as
> where  is the sigmoid function.
> For multiclass classification, K trees (for K classes) are built at each of the  iterations. The probability that
> belongs to class k is modeled as a softmax of the
> values.
>
> Note that even for a classification task, the
> sub-estimator is still a regressor, not a classifier. This is because the sub-estimators are trained to predict (negative) gradients, which are always continuous quantities.